# EditText added programmatically differes from XML version

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have an XML layout containing a EditText and 2 buttons. If I click on the plus button, a new edittext is programatically added. This works, but the edittext looks different. According to the XML the edittext defined in XML does not have any special attributes, so I believe its not a particular layout setting.

My question is how do I make my programmatically added EditText's look the same?

The EditText's containing the numbers are my programmatically added edittext's. The empty ones are creating in the XML.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [tozz.nl](http://www.tozz.nl/temp/screenshot.png))</sub>

Code:

```
        LinearLayout baseLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.baseLayout);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayout.setId(100 + numPlayers);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        editText.setText(editText.toString().substring(25, 30));

        ImageButton delButton = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
        delButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);

        linearLayout.addView(editText);
        linearLayout.addView(delButton);

        baseLayout.addView(linearLayout);
```

My XML is as following:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearPlayer1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPlayer1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addPlayer1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_input_add" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post the code where you make and add those additional `EditTexts`.

Comment: Its simple:   EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
editText.setText(editText.toString().substring(25, 30));

Comment: And into which type of layout do you add them and how?

Answer (score 5):

Luksprog answered my question:

> pass the Activity Context and not the Application Context when creating the new views.

Answer (score 3):

Adding those views with the correct `LayoutParams` should make the `EditText` be like the initial one from the layout:

```
    linearLayout.addView(editText, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
    linearLayout.addView(delButton, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    baseLayout.addView(linearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I meant. With your code the layout (width, button to the right, etc) is fixed. But the EditText still has a different style. Please see the new screenshot. WHat I mean is that the XML edittext just has a neat line as input, while my added edittext's are gray boxes. ![new screenshot](http://www.tozz.nl/temp/screenshot2.png)

Comment: @user1750795 Can you post the xml layout code for the `EditText`? the added `EditTexts` have the appearance of a disabled `EditText` box(`setEnabled(false)` somewhere in your code?). Are you using some libraries in your app?

Comment: @user1750795 You haven't answered all my question from the previous comment. Also pass the `Activity` `Context` and **not** the `Application` `Context` when creating the new views. Also mention the Android version on which you are testing.

Comment: Ah! Your comment regarding the Activity Context instead of the Application context fixed it. I've changed getApplicationContext() to v.getContext() and that solves my issue. Thank you very much for your time and effort!